# Cannot visit some tags in Stack OverFlow

Tags: support

I am experiencing a little problem on this site lately. When I visit on some tags, they load perfectly except for the two tags:

- [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server)
- [java](/questions/tagged/java)

I always get this error page. I'm using Google Chrome (*latest version*).

Here's what I did before I posted the question:

- Clear History and All others (*nothing happens*)
- Reinstall Chrome (*nothing happens*)
- Check for internet connection (*nothing happens*)
- Restart PC (*nothing happens*)
- Checking for proxy (*found none*)
- Checking for host file located on `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` if a link was added and found nothing.
- Use other browser (*same thing happen*)

[image]

[image]

Any other ideas?

Comment: Nope, cannot reproduce that here. Are you behind a firewall or proxy?

Comment: hello @MartijnPieters nope. Just weird. All tags loads fine except for the two, `Java` and `Sql Server`.

Comment: Where in the world are you? What DNS are you using?

Comment: Something tells me that we might have the same ISP. I can't reproduce this, but here's something you can do. Set your DNS servers to 4.2.2.2 and 4.2.2.3 in your network preferences and see if it still reproduces.

Comment: @Oded the dns was obtained automatically, i did not have any configurations on my network.

Comment: @TinyTimPost hello kabayan. When i set the dns it loads very very slowly and same with the other links.

Comment: The one thing I strongly suspect is a caching proxy on your ISP side, but you've apparently ruled that out. I just don't know what else you could try other than a different connection if one is available. It's just so ***weird*** that it's only those two tag pages.

Comment: Note that the error message `Unable to resolve the server's DNS address` only applies to the domain name, and should not take any other part of the URL into account. I'd say something must be messing with that specific URL on your computer, but even that is odd as a browser will first get the IP address (passing the DNS service the domain part of the URL) and only then send a request to that IP address, to get the specific path from that server. Hence, it would be very hard for other software to mess with a specific URL, in a way to get DNS errors. But: your **Firefox shows another error**.

Comment: Any virus scanner you can disable?

Comment: Are these tags in your ignored/preferred list? And if it's triggered by some keywords in the URL, what about similar tags, such as [sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [sql-server-2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008), [java-ee](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee), [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), ...?

Comment: @Arjan nope, I have no tags that are added on the ignored list. I already disabled the antivirus.